# Django form with ModelMultipleChoiceField rendered empty

Tags: python, django

I have trouble setting up a form with a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` where the queryset depends on the user. My goal is to implement an export function.

My view looks like this:

```
class ExportView(FormView):
    template_name = 'ExportTemplate.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form_class = ExportForm(user = request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form_class})

    def get_success_url(self):
        return '/addrbook/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

form:

```
class ExportForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        usersContacts = ContactManager().getAllUsersContacts()
        self.contactList = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = usersContacts[str(user)])
        print(usersContacts[str(user)])
        super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I verified that the queryset is not empty, it contains a list of model objects.

My template looks like this:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

the only thing that gets rendered is the submit button.

Another thing that left me completely unsure of python basics is that this code:

```
class ExportForm(forms.Form):
    contactList = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = [])

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        usersContacts = ContactManager().getAllUsersContacts()
        self.contactList.queryset = usersContacts[str(user)]
        print(usersContacts[str(user)])
        super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

returned the runtime error:

```
'ExportForm' object has no attribute 'contactList'
```

How is it possible? the contactList member is part of the ExportForm class definition and 'self' should point to an object of that class.

Could someone explain to me why the form field is rendered empty and/or point me to a better way to pass the user to the form?

Edit: here are the changes i made to the answer to get it working, although i now stumbled upon a different problem(the field expects a queryset, and not a list of model objects):

View:

```
class ExportView(FormView):
template_name = 'ExportTemplate.html'
form_class = ExportForm

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ExportView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```

form:

```
class ExportForm(forms.Form):
contactList = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Contact.objects.none())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs['user']
    kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    usersContacts = ContactManager().getAllUsersContacts()
    self.fields['contactList'].queryset = usersContacts[str(user)]
    print(self.fields['contactList'].queryset)
```

Comment: You get an attribute error when you use `self.contactList` because `forms.Form` uses a metaclass which stores the fields in the `base_fields` dictionary. But as I say in my answer below, you should use `self.fields` to edit the fields for an individual form instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should pass the `user` to the form every time you instantiate it, not just in the `get` method. The way to do this with `FormView` is to override `get_form_kwargs`.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ExportForm, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs[user] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```

You can then remove your `get()` method.

Then, in your form class, you should use the `none()` method instead of an empty list to get an empty queryset. In the `__init__` method you can pop the user from `kwargs`, and then call `super()` before you edit the fields. You edit the `contactList` field via `self.fields` instead of `self.contactList`. Note that the recommended style for field names in Django is `contact_list` instead of `contactList`.

```
class ExportForm(forms.Form):
    contactList = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        usersContacts = ContactManager().getAllUsersContacts()
        self.fields['contactList'].queryset = usersContacts[str(user)]
```

You haven't shown the `ContactManager()` code, but using `str(user)` as the dictionary key looks fragile. It would probably be better to use `user.pk` or `user.username` instead.

Comment: thanks for pointing out so many issues :) i will implement those changes and see how it goes

Comment: wasn't 'self.form_class' the instantiated form? it is defined as ExportForm(user = request.user)

Comment: Yes my mistake, it was the instantiated form. Perhaps `form` would have been a better name for an instantiated form rather than `form_class` ;)

Comment: yeah, i copied it from an answer i found on SO

Comment: thanks, that problem is solved, but now i need to get the collection as a queryset. Might get a bit complicated because contacts are shared with single users and with groups that users are in

Comment: Maybe you could show me a more elegant way to make the init function of ExportForm work? super() throws an error when there is an additional keyword argument. You can see my version in my edited question.

Comment: You've pretty much figured it out. Just use `user = kwargs.pop('user')`. Note that I haven't specified `None` as a default - that means you'll get an explicit error if `user` is missing from `kwargs`.